# Run python Script that reruns every 4 hours at system startup

Tags: scripts, python

I am fairly new to ubuntu/linux and python so I beg forgiveness in advance.  I have a small python script that I typically start in a terminal screen.  This script runs a simple task then sets a timer to run the same task again in 4 hours.  I want to run this in the background and I also want it to start running when the server boots.  I am sure this question has been asked before, but I have not had much luck finding the solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Basic cod below.

```
import os
import datetime
from threading import Timer

x = datetime.datetime.today()

if x.hour+4 > 23
    do some stuff
else
    do other stuff

Function()
    Repeat above stuff

t = Timer(sec, Function)
t.start()
```

Comment: There are less complex methods: 'at' jobs, 'cron' jobs, and systemd timers.

Comment: Based on what I a seeing it would appear that a cron job is what I want.  Is there a way to confirm that the job ran?

Comment: Use a >> output file

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for my ignorance.  Just getting started in python and linux.

Comment: Python is so Universal...Great Choice!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that needs to know, as it was mentioned in the comments I edited the crontab file.  I actually only needed it daily, so it was very simple.

```
crontab -e
```

On the last line I added:

```
0 1 * * * python /file_location/file.py
```

This runs file.py at 1:00 AM.

```
(minutes) (Hour) (day of month) (day of week) command
```